# Sticky Row with Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sticky

I have the following row in my header:

```
<div id="shop-cart-count-mobile" class="visible-xs">
    <a href="/shop/cart">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-9 mt10 mb10">
                <h4>In Your Cart</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-right mt10 mb10">
                <h4>
                    <span class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></span>
                    4</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

And I want to make it a sticky row, so that when the user scrolls down, it stays at the top of the screen.  It is not currently right at the top, its a few rows in.

I tried using the `position:sticky` but no luck, and I'm not sure with bootstrap3 there is a built in functionality to do this.  Is there an easy solution I'm missing here?

I built a codepen, and still can't get anywhere with it: https://codepen.io/chud37/pen/oNZzLwx

Answer (score 1):

try using top 0

```
.your-class {
     position: -webkit-sticky;
     position: sticky;
     top: 0;
   }
```

Comment: See the codepen: https://codepen.io/chud37/pen/oNZzLwx  I can't get it to work.

Comment: add these styles to header in your example and z-index = 10

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent_class {
     position: sticky;
     top:0;
    }
```

You have to specify the position `top:0;` to make it work
Here's a video about CSS sticky position by Web dev simplified
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzjU1GmKosQ

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. I know about the top:0, but it still doesnt work.  See my codepen: https://codepen.io/chud37/pen/oNZzLwx